# Proxy Authentication Required for WindowBuilder

Tags: eclipse, proxy

I am having trouble installing WindowBuilder at my workplace.

I did the following settings:

[image]

But I get this error:

[image]

My connection settings:

[image]

Comment: Check the host and port settings from your browser's connection settings...if your browser is able to connect to internet

Comment: I used this website because my browser's connection settings doesn't show me anything: http://aruljohn.com/details.php
But it still doesn't work after changing the settings through Manual. I also included my username and password.

Comment: Are you able to connect to any other update site from eclipse..or generically speaking is eclipse able to connect to internet ?...and why you are not able to view the connection settings of your browser ?

Comment: Yes, the internal browser can connect to the internet. It's set to the configuration script.

Comment: You know what, I checked the configuration script and got the right host name from there. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: good to know that it worked :)

Comment: It is not necessary to edit your post and add "Solved", as it would invalidate the purpose of Stack Overflow as a question and answer site (it would no longer be a question). If you feel this question warrants a proper answer, you can post one. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301